# XSD validate element depending on parent node

Tags: xml, xsd

`<a>` can have text and `<i>` tag, `<i>` can have text and `<a>` tag inside.

```
<a>lol<i>so rad</i></a> - valid
<i>so sweet <a>lolz</a></i> - valid
```

My current solution has a serious flaw, next one is "valid", cos inner `<a>` wrapped in `<i>`.

```
<a>so what now <i>so sweet <a>lolz</a></i></a>
```

I want to test `<i>` element parent, so i can forbid `<a>` child elements if it is inside `<a>` tag.

Current XSD:

```
<xs:element name="a">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="bodyMixed">
          <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:anyURI" use="required" />
          <xs:attribute name="target" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="bodyMixed" mixed="true">
    <xs:group ref="fontStyle" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="basic" mixed="true">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:group name="fontStyle">
    <xs:choice>
       <xs:element name="i" type="basic"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:group>
```

Comment: I think that also "a" should be mixed="true"...

Comment: `<a>` extends `bodyMixed` so it is already `mixed=True`

Comment: I say that because I'm not really sure that mixed is inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this kind of situation is with assertions, either in Schematron or in XSD 1.1.  Since XSD assertions cannot usefully look up in the tree, you'll want to write an assertion for `a` which asserts that the `a` element in question has no descendants named `a`.  So it's the outer `a`, not the inner `a`, which will be invalid.  (Schematron is less finicky about what assertions can refer to, so you can easily write a Schematron rule to make the inner but not the outer `a`, or the `i` within an `a`, be invalid.)

If you don't have access to assertions (e.g. because you are in XSD 1.0), you will need to use the limited context-awareness offered by local element declarations and described in [this old XSD working paper](http://www.w3.org/2000/04/26-csrules.html).